# Where to upload large (0.5Gb) weights anonymously?

Tags: reference-request

I need to upload a number of checkpoints for ConvNets (weights + optimizers, all dicts of pytorch tensors), each about 0.5Gb anonymously. I don't want to use Google Drive. I trained models on the university cluster (if it's relevant).

Where can I load these files anonymously? The files must be publicly available, but my identity must remain anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[file.io](https://www.file.io/) or [transfer.sh](http://transfer.sh) are good choices. transfer.sh has a 14 day lifespan for all files, while you can increase or decrease the lifespan on file.io. Additionally, you can use both from a command line or terminal via `curl`, and they're anonymous.

Comment: neither did the job, unfortunately

Comment: What were the problems you had with the sites?

Comment: For file.io the file is deleted after the first download, and the link has the same problem as Google Drive (wget doesn't recognize it), and 14 days limit doesn't work for me, it must be much longer

Comment: I download from their site using `wget`, you have to rename the output file and set its file extension though. I normally use `wget -O new_filename https://file.io/XXXXX` or just download it and rename it later. You can also increase the 14 day limit by using  `w`, `m`, or `y` to set expiration in weeks, months, or years. I haven't used that before but assume it'd be used as `curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://file.io/?expires=1y`. Check https://www.file.io/#one for more usage details. Hope this helps